# I want to improve execution time of query

Tags: sql-server

I have query to load 1.5 billion records and I want to improve execution time

```
SELECT TOP (20) a.code AS No_, 
                lastyear =
(
    SELECT SUM(c.[Sales Amount (Actual)])
    FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Value Entry] c
    WHERE c.[Source Type] = 1
          AND c.[Global Dimension 1 Code] = a.Code
          AND c.[Source No_] = 'WOR07'
          AND c.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '7/16/2018'
), 
                CurrentYear =
(
    SELECT SUM(c.[Sales Amount (Actual)])
    FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Value Entry] c
    WHERE c.[Source Type] = 1
          AND c.[Global Dimension 1 Code] = a.Code
          AND c.[Source No_] = 'WOR07'
          AND c.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '01/01/2019' AND '7/16/2019'
)
FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Item Category] a
ORDER BY CurrentYear DESC;
```

Comment: Try to check an Execution Plan of the query and optimize it

Comment: Are the tables indexed?  If so, on what columns?  There is way too much missing information here for anyone to help .

Comment: no the table is not indexed, can you mention what information you need in details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an index on the table using the fields you are looking up data on. For added speed, you can INCLUDE the monetary fields you need to reference. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_SourceType_GlobalDimension1Code_SourceNo_PostingDate
ON [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Value Entry] (
    [Source Type], 
    [Global Dimension 1 Code],
    [Source No_],
    [Posting Date]
    )
INCLUDE ([Sales Amount (Actual)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to steal @Laughing Vergil's thunder, but I have a suggestion on top of his/her answer (and I don't have the ranking to comment). Your index should be created such that the columns are ordered in decreasing specificity. My guess is that your index *should* look like this to maximize your performance:

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_SourceType_GlobalDimension1Code_SourceNo_PostingDate
ON [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Value Entry] (
    [Source No_],
    [Posting Date]
    [Global Dimension 1 Code],
    [Source Type], 
)
INCLUDE ([Sales Amount (Actual)])
```

This assumes that [Source No_] is a unique key on another table, [Posting Date] is a date (which is *pretty* unique), and the code and types are very small lookup-like values that only have a few different possible values.

One thing to note, however, is that this index is designed *specifically* for this query. If you take out [Source No_] from future queries, you may need to create another index to handle that particular situation as well. Index maintenance is a constant battle for DBAs and there are much smarter people (aka, [Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/)) to help you through those challenges.

Comment: Here's why I prefer the other index field order. Since [Source Type], [Global Dimension 1 Code], and [Source No_] are all being looked up on a single value, but [Posting Date] is a range, seeking the first three values will give you a continuous block of index entries, ordered by the range value. This results in an index seek to the first key, then a continuous sequential scan to the last key. Placing the date in a different position means that the individual keys being sought will be separated  in the index, and multiple seeks will have to be performed.

Comment: That's a good point on the Posting Date, I really appreciate that you brought that up. I think, I would still argue for the order of [Source No_], [Global Dimension 1 Code], and then [Source Type] in terms of specificity. But that's also from an incomplete knowledge of the database.